# How to return result of this recursive function / overall improve it?

Tags: python-3.x, recursion

So I have this function definition so far:

```
def reverseString(string):
    if len(string) == 1:
        return string
    else:
        reverse = string[0] 
        reverseString(string[1:]) 
        print(reverse, end='')
```

I have two main problems.

First of all, I need to return the reversed function instead of printing it. I am not sure how to do that, because when you remove " end = '' " from the statement it only returns nothing.

Second of all, the program seems to work fine when I assign a value to the string variable in the body of the program. However, I need to ask for an input instead of assigning it myself.

What can I do to improve it? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the recursive solution:

```
def reverse_string(string):
    if not string: return ""
    return reverse_string(string[1:]) + string[0]


print(reverse_string("ABC"))
# CBA
```

Also you can reverse a string as follow:

```
s = "ABC"
s = s[::-1]
```

Comment: Thank you this was helpful!